# Dataproc Job not giving any output

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

I have submitted spark job through airflow sometimes job works and sometimes it don't give output at all .
Even after 2-3 hrs of waiting job is not giving any detail apart from
`Waiting for job output...`

I am using `dataproc-1-4-deb10`

Its simple job like pulling data from jdbc using pysaprk. Also it works without error sometimes and sometimes doesnt at all.

Comment: Can you share details about the job? Also, can you check behavior by just running simple PiSpark job multiple times  and verify if you get job output?

Comment: @Animesh Is is possible due to yarn failure .  I dont know anything about hadoop just a guess.

Comment: I m facing the same. The same job is already running but for some reason gcloud probably haven't even submitted to yarn cluster. I don't see the jobs as submitted in yarn UI.

Comment: @ShubhamAsabe I facing the same issue. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @RaviJain Nope just restarting the job worked for me but suggesting you to raise a google ticket.

Comment: @ShubhamAsabe what I have figured out is that the job was stuck at the accepted state due to no resources (memory) available in the yarn queue. However, the cluster had a lot of resources available. 

I tried the below properties but still, each application submit took 896m for AM. and after certain apps the submission will stuck. 

yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent changed from 0.25 to 0.95

yarn:yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=13544